# Enthusiast badge

Tags: discussion, badges

I was hoping for enthusiast badge which requires 30 consecutive days of visit.On 27/10/2015 around 00.10 am,it was  showing 7/30 means 7 days out of 30 but today it is displaying 1/30.If anyone could explain reason behind this it would be a great help?

Comment: When, yesterday?

Comment: It may be to do with the browser's cookies or something being wiped after week - you also need to be logged in as well

Comment: @muru Oh! sorry ,I had added the date in my question now.

Comment: To count as a visit you actually have to *do* something, not just load the page.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by do something as I only read questions asked by others so possibly you may be correct.

Comment: @RahulRaj I meant, what time yesterday? Before 5:30 am?

Comment: Yes,around 00:10 am.

Comment: @Seth sure? I could swear that had worked for me once or twice. I was active in chat though, probably, but not on the main site.

Comment: @RahulRaj Days are counted in UTC. That means if you're in time zone +5 (just an example), the "StackExchange day" will end at 00:00 UTC which is 05:00 local time for you. That might have caused confusion, maybe?

Comment: Yes,it is given that days are counted in UTC but I thought that it would not be issue.And,thanks you cleared my confusion.

Comment: @byte "doing" something isn't hard. All you have to do is click on a question. But yes, I'm sure.

Comment: @Seth You sure? Opening http://unix.stackexchange.com and quickly opening my profile triggered the "Last seen" thing, which was set to "5 seconds ago" (apparently the time at which I loaded the first page)

Comment: @Seth I'm pretty sure that's not true. A visit is, well a _visit_, you don't need to do anything other than log in.

Comment: @terdon but unless something changed the system doesn't count those days for the badge unless you *do* something. I will try to hunt down my sources again. Been this way for ages.

Comment: @Seth back when I was working towards these badges, all I had to do when not at home to actually use the site was visit and the count was updated. This was more than a year ago.

Comment: @terdon You bashed Seth for cheating in chat, but you're no better :D. Next step is setting up automatic startup and a startup job to quickly open all the sites we're registered to :D

Comment: @kos well, I did actually visit the site! :P

Comment: @terdon Yes I know. :D And to be *really* honest, I *might* have done that on Italian.SE as well (obviously no admission intended with that). :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't say how? but I am sure that is not system fault.

For consecutive days, days are counted in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). In India (since you are from Gujrat) the new day counted after **5:30**.

But you can know which day(s) you have missed.

Go to profile and click on consecutive days link.

For example:

1.My consecutive days in U&L. The gaps shows not visited days.

> [image: Imgur]

2.My consecutive days in AU. No gaps :)

> [image: Imgur]